# How to redirect to a view after a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a some social sharing links in my HTML template. I can share to Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter and Whatsapp, but I want to redirect to a URL (views) in Django that would give 100 points to the user that is sharing the post using the social share link.

How can I asynchronously redirect to that view in the background?

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work

```html
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{url_string}}" data-layout="button_count" onclick="window.open({% url 'core:social-share' %},'_blank'); return false;"></div>
```

These are my shareable links#

```html
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=https://youtube.com/user/desphixs/&amp;title=WelcomeTo{{company.name}}&amp;summary={{company.name}}&amp;source=mywebsite" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
  <small>Share on Linkedin</small>
</a>

<a class="share-linkedin text-white mr-2" href="whatsapp://send?text={{content_string}}{{url_string}}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
  <small>Share on Whatsapp</small>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether there is a way to reliably check whether a user actually shared content or just clicked your link and did nothing.

But you could send a `POST` to a Django endpoint which adds the 100 pts to user's points, which answers with an [HTTP303](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) to redirect the user to another page.

A clientside solution would look the same:

1. Send a `POST` to any endpoint
2. `location.href` to redirect.

Comment: I too don't even know if there is a way to check if user actually posted, because that should be crucial to awarding the points

Comment: @thomas-junk i thought ajax can be used. Can you please show me a code on how to send a post to django endpoint as you stated above?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @DestinyFranks perhaps we are nice and optimistic and reward good intent.